# Swift UITableViewController numberOfSections index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] With Static Cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsrangeexception

I have a `UITableViewController`, with a static 5 sections and 2 rows per sections, but the last section with 1 row.

I've created the table in storyboards and set the number of sections and rows via storyboards. In the protocol functions I've also set the correct number of rows and sections:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (section == 4) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 2
    }
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I believe this error is related to the `numberOfSections` function because if I change it from 5 to 0, it runs fine. I don't understand how the array of sections can be zero when I've defined it in storyboards to be 5. Is there a simple solution I'm not seeing?

I also have the delegate sources linked up, and my data source is not any kind of array, as the entire table was created in storyboards, and contains labels, etc.

**EDIT**

Code for entire view controller:

```
import UIKit

class RideSummaryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var ratingLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var originStreetLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var originCityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var destStreetLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var destCityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var rateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var paymentButton: UIButton!

var paymentText = "Request Payment"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    self.paymentButton.setTitle(paymentText, for: .normal)

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (section == 4) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 2
    }
}

/*
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you selected Static cells in the storyboard? You haven't populated dynamic cells by any chance. Although I don't think its possible to create sections with dynamic cells. Could you post the whole controller?

Comment: Yes I've selected Static cells in the storyboard. Posting the entire view controller class now.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and it took me some time to find my error.

My mistake was that there was still a cell left on the **storyboard**. After I have deleted the cell and the corresponding section/group it worked how it should.